# Writing pyspark dataframe to text file without trailing spaces in hdfs

Tags: pyspark

I have pyspark dataframe. which  having following data:-

```
id      name         address
101010  xyz abc      jkdjfkd kdfjd
101001  ygbgnt bnbnb dfkdjfd kdjfkd kdfjkd
```

I want to write given data to textfile with fixed length with '|' delimiter. Delimiter should come after fixed position of each column.first pipe will come after 7 position , second one in 23 position and third one 52 position.

File format and length  should be

```
101010|xyz abc        |jkdjfkd kdfjd                |
101001|ygbgnt bnbnb   |dfkdjfd kdjfkd kdfjkd        |
```

I am using rpad to achieve the given file format. But In this solution i am getting trailing spaces after the **name** and **address** column. I do not want trailing spaces.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by `consider as null`

Comment: I  mean should not be blank spaces.

Comment: but if your pipes have to be at certain positions, there has to be white spaces, otherwise how do you want to fill the gap?

Comment: I have the same opinion. But is there any alternate solution to achieve the requirements.

Comment: There is not. It's not a programming problem, but a simple file formatting problem. If you want fixed width format, there must be white spaces.

Comment: Ok fine thanks for  your explanations.